# Looking for a Star Wars comic where Han carries Leia on his shoulders?

Tags: star-wars, comics, episode-identification

At the beginning of the 1980s, during my high school years, while on the school bus, I remember seeing one of my classmates reading a *Star Wars* comic. The only thing I remember from that pulp magazine was its cover. It was a scene in ochre colors with Han and Leia in the foreground. The background was a battlefield in a planet like Tatooine with the Millennium Falcon crashed and in flames. A star destroyer and some tie fighters firing from the sky. That’s everything I can remember but what really brought my attention was that Han was carrying Leia on his shoulders. Unfortunately, I wasn’t able to have in my hands the comic, given that when I asked the mate to lend me the comic — one day later — he had exchanged it for a Batman comic. I don’t remember if it was a DC or a Marvel or any other publisher. I have never seen that comic again.

All these years I have been trying to find the comic but unsuccessfully. Then, few months ago I decided to draw and paint the cover as close as I remember from almost 40 years ago.

Can someone remember what comic had Han carrying Leia on his shoulders?

[image: Han carrying Leia on his shoulders. They are both holding blasters. There is technological wreckage in the background behind them, and TIE fighters are visible in the sky.]

Comment: Most likely a marvel one in the 80s, have a browse through https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/20111/star_wars_annual_1979_-_1983 and https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/20108/star_wars_1977_-_1986 for covers. I had a quick skim, but didn't see anything

Comment: +1 for taking the effort to draw that

Comment: Were the characters dressed the way you show in your version?  Because that would suggest that the comic was written before *The Empire Strikes Back*.

Comment: Also had a quick skim through https://nl.pinterest.com/jtarchives/star-wars-comics-cover-gallery/ but don't see anything which relates to your picture

Comment: Well, I looked as well on the web,  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  couldn't find anything. Great drawing tho! Kudos for sure!

Comment: Not a match but maybe this? Marvel UK Return of the Jedi Annual 1984. https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi_Annual_1984

Comment: BTW, is that possible, that original image comes from this cover (with some editions): https://www.vintagemovieposters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/IMG_2815.jpeg

Comment: May be you can try to find that magazine in the library?

Comment: Where were you living when you saw this? If it's a UK-specific Marvel cover (eg), that could narrow the search.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really looking for a cover (rather than an interior page) from the 1980s or earlier, then all appearances are that it does not exist.  There are numerous sources online with complete sets of cover images for the *Star Wars* comics, and nothing like that appears.  For example, [Marvel has all the covers of the original 1977–1986 comic series.](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/20108/star_wars_1977_-_1986)  (These are actually the reprint versions of the covers, but the changes from the originals are minor.)

An even more comprehensive (but with smaller preview images) collection of covers [is available from RebelScum.com](http://www.rebelscum.com/comicbooks.asp).  The collection includes comics from all publishers.  I have looked over all the 1970s and 1980s comic covers, and none of them resembles what you have drawn all that closely.  There are very few images of anybody carrying Leia (far fewer than the number of drawings of people carrying Luke, it seems)—I presume to emphasize her independent demeanor.  The closest I could find was this cover of issue no. 53 (November, 1981), which has much the same color scheme as your drawing, but obviously the context in which Princess Leia is being carried is quite different.

[image: Issue No. 53]

Most (but, as far as I can tell, not all) of the interiors of the 1970s and 1980s comics [can also be found online for free](https://www.comicextra.com/comic/star-wars-1977).  I paged through a number of issues and did not see any interior images that resembled your picture of Han carrying Leia either.

Comment: How does this stormtrooper ascent the circus ladder with only one arm free. Why is the other stormtrooper Zaku-sized.

Answer (score 2):

It could be something like this:
[Return of the Jedi](https://www.noosfere.org/livres/niourf.asp?numlivre=1972757557) by James KAHN

Not an exact match, but quite similar, maybe memory changed the picture over the time)

ps. origin comes from the movie poster: https://www.vintagemovieposters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/IMG_2815.jpeg

[image]